# Apps Script trigger function keeps on running though the trigger has been deleted

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a trigger which will first execute after 5 minutes, the when the trigger function starts executing, the trigger is deleted at first place , then the required code executes, and then new trigger is created which executes in 1 minutes. Also I have a condition where in the trigger is deleted and never created.. but the trigger still continues to execute.
I get total_uploads value as 29393, but it ended up adding nearly 100k records.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Fetch CoA')
    .addItem('Fetch CoA', 'main')
    .addToUi();
}

function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var config = ss.getSheetByName("Config");
  var hostname = config.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var authorization = config.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  var coaID = config.getRange(4, 2).getValue();
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  documentProperties.setProperties({
    'hostname': hostname,
    'authorization': authorization,
    'coaID': coaID,
    'offset': '0',
    'is_last_set': 0
  });
  var coaSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COA");

  if (coaSheet.getLastRow() > 1) {
    coaSheet.deleteRows(1, coaSheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  }
  console.log("Getting CoA Validaton");
  writeCOA();
}

function writeCOA() {
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var hostname = documentProperties.getProperty('hostname');
  var authorization = documentProperties.getProperty('authorization');
  var coaID = documentProperties.getProperty('coaID');
  var offset = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('offset'));
  var is_last_set = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('is_last_set'));
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorization
    }
  };

  var today = new Date();

  console.log("Writing the uploads array");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var coaSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COA");
  coaSheet.getRange("A1:D1").setValues([["id", "account_number", "created_at", "updated_at"]]);
  var rowNum = 2;
  var uploads = [];
  var next_page = true;
  var total_uploads = "...";

  console.log("Getting all Account numbers for CoA: " + coaID);

  while (next_page) {
    documentProperties.setProperty('next_page', next_page);
    if (isTimeUp(today) && is_last_set == 0) {
      console.log("RepeatWriteCoA triggered");
      // schedule a trigger for a different function
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("repeatWriteCoA")
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(5)
        .create();
      break;
    }
    console.log(`Getting uploads ${offset} to ${offset + 500} of ${total_uploads}`);
    var platformUrl = `${hostname}/api/v3/chart_of_accounts/${coaID}/account_numbers?limit=500&offset=${offset}`;
    //console.log(platformUrl);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(platformUrl, options);
    var jsonResponse = response.getContentText();
    var page_of_uploads = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
    total_uploads = page_of_uploads['meta']['total'];
    documentProperties.setProperty('total_uploads', total_uploads);
    uploads = page_of_uploads['account_numbers'];
    try {
      offset = page_of_uploads['meta']['next']['offset'];
      documentProperties.setProperty('offset', offset);
    } catch (Exception) {
      next_page = false;
      documentProperties.setProperty('next_page', next_page);
      console.log("Exception in getting the next page offset hence stopping the loop");
      deleteTriggers();
      // For last set of records that needs to added in our spreadsheet
      console.log("Adding Last set of Records..");
      for (i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
        acc_number = uploads[i].account_number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/g, '-');
        coaSheet.getRange("A" + rowNum + ":D" + rowNum).setValues([[uploads[i].id, acc_number, uploads[i].created_at, uploads[i].updated_at]]);
        rowNum += 1;
        documentProperties.setProperty('rowNum', rowNum);
      }
      console.log("End of Last set of Records..");
      is_last_set = 1;
    }
    console.log("Adding to spreadsheet");
    for (i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
      acc_number = uploads[i].account_number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/g, '-');
      coaSheet.getRange("A" + rowNum + ":D" + rowNum).setValues([[uploads[i].id, acc_number, uploads[i].created_at, uploads[i].updated_at]]);
      rowNum += 1;
      documentProperties.setProperty('rowNum', rowNum);
    }
    console.log("End of adding rows");
    if (offset >= total_uploads) {
      deleteTriggers();
    }
  }
  documentProperties.setProperty('is_last_set', is_last_set);
}

function repeatWriteCoA() {
  console.log("Triggered RepeatFunction... Running from Repeat function");
  // Delete trigger , so that new function wont be trigger untill this function ends   
  deleteTriggers();
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var hostname = documentProperties.getProperty('hostname');
  var authorization = documentProperties.getProperty('authorization');
  var coaID = documentProperties.getProperty('coaID');
  var offset = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('offset'));
  var next_page = documentProperties.getProperty('next_page');
  var rowNum = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('rowNum'));
  var total_uploads = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('total_uploads'));

  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorization
    }
  };

  var today = new Date();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var coaSheet = ss.getSheetByName("COA");
  var is_last_set = parseInt(documentProperties.getProperty('is_last_set'));
  console.log("Getting all Account numbers for CoA: " + coaID);
  while (next_page) {    
    if (is_last_set == 1) {
      console.log('last set already executed');
      break;
    }
    console.log(`Getting uploads ${offset} to ${offset + 500} of ${total_uploads}`);
    var platformUrl = `${hostname}/api/v3/chart_of_accounts/${coaID}/account_numbers?limit=500&offset=${offset}`;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(platformUrl, options);
    var jsonResponse = response.getContentText();
    var page_of_uploads = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
    total_uploads = page_of_uploads['meta']['total'];
    uploads = page_of_uploads['account_numbers'];
    try {
      offset = page_of_uploads['meta']['next']['offset'];
      documentProperties.setProperty('offset', offset);
    } catch (Exception) {
      next_page = false;
      documentProperties.setProperty('next_page', next_page);
      console.log("Exception in getting the next page offset hence stopping the loop");
      // For last set of records that needs to added in our spreadsheet
      console.log("Adding Last set of Records..");
      for (i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
        acc_number = uploads[i].account_number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/g, '-');
        coaSheet.getRange("A" + rowNum + ":D" + rowNum).setValues([[uploads[i].id, acc_number, uploads[i].created_at, uploads[i].updated_at]]);
        rowNum += 1;
        documentProperties.setProperty('rowNum', rowNum);
      }
      console.log("End of Last set of Records..");
      is_last_set = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
      acc_number = uploads[i].account_number.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/g, '-');
      coaSheet.getRange("A" + rowNum + ":D" + rowNum).setValues([[uploads[i].id, acc_number, uploads[i].created_at, uploads[i].updated_at]]);
      rowNum += 1;
      documentProperties.setProperty('rowNum', rowNum);
    }
    // Creating new trigger so that it will trigger this function next time ,
    // this time we are creating the trigger with 1 min
    if (offset <= total_uploads && isTimeUp(today) && is_last_set == 0) {
      console.log("RepeatWriteCoA triggered");
      // schedule a trigger for a different function
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("repeatWriteCoA")
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(1)
        .create();
      break;
    }
  }
  documentProperties.setProperty('is_last_set', is_last_set);
}

function isTimeUp(today) {
  var now = new Date();
  console.log(now.getTime() - today.getTime());
  return now.getTime() - today.getTime() > 240000;
  // 240000 = 4 mins; this is the threshold limit
  // you are free to setup your own threshold limit
}

function deleteTriggers() {
  // Loop over all triggers.
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (allTriggers.length > 0) {
    console.log("Deleting trigger....");
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
      // If the current trigger is the correct one, delete it.
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, Thanks @JamesZ

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Since your trigger creation does not include checking to see that the trigger doesn't already exist I would suspect that you might be creating more triggers than you realize.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, The problem is I have deleted the trigger , but still the trigger function gets executed.

Comment: @Cooper, Though I haven't checked that whether the trigger already exists or not while creating trigger, but I have always deleted the trigger at the first place when the function repeatWriteCoA is executed, which will make sure that when I create a new trigger , no previous trigger exist.

Comment: Okay that's fine.  Now please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I was debugging more on this , I got the issue resolve now, now once the offset value reaches to total_uploads value, no new triggers are creating. I have added my updated code is above code snippet. I just added some more conditions and checks for counts. Thank you all!

Comment: @Cooper, Do you still need minimal reproducible example for this?

Comment: Definitely do.  Current script is a bit to complicated.  Just focus on reproducing the problem you want us to address.  It may take some time to determine what portion of the script you need to focus on but I'd rather you spend your time doing that rather than my time.